# using regex to replace multiple character

Tags: regex, .htaccess

customers enter serial numbers on my website then I have a webservice to check it,  I wonder if its possible for me to use httaccess and regex to replace any Os entered in the serial number with zeros.  I can push out an updated httaccess file much faster than updating,testing and deploying the application.

the following example will just replace the last occurrence  is there a way to have it replace every occurrence for a serial number like `HI-QWVo-3UGoS-YTSQJ`

```
^SN=(.*)o(.*)   SN$10$2
```

Comment: Provide some example of input URIs and rewritten URIs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^SN(.*)o(.*)$ SN$10$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is very good for replacing one "o" => "0", how to do to replace hop-loop-myfoo-mybar0 to get h0p-l00p-myf00-mybar0? I'm interested by your global replacement expression...